# Have cmake check version at install time

Tags: cmake

I have a cmake script that add a "add_custom_command" that generate a program version anytime the program is compiled. That creates a Header File. It works fine...

Now, what I want to do is to have cmake use value from said file during installation and packaging.
Parsing the file is of no worry. What I don't know is how do  I ask cmake to parse it just before installing, since it would have been modified during the compilation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out some of the capabilities of the [`INSTALL` command](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command%3ainstall)

```
INSTALL(CODE "CMAKE_CODE_THAT_PARSES_FILE")
```

or

```
INSTALL(SCRIPT CMAKE_Parsing_Script.cmake)
```

These will be executed at install time.